# How to choose a winning strategy for this 2-4 player-game, algorithm only

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, game-theory

Here is a sequence of integers

```
a1, a2, ... an,   1<=ai<=100  2<=n<=100.
```

The sequence of integers are arranged in non-decreasing order.

`m(2<=m<=4)` players take turn to choose one of these integers to tag. If an integer is tagged twice, it's occupied by the player who chose it last, and the player gets another chance to tag. (Obviously, the integer can't be tagged the third time:) )

The sum of the integers the player occupies is the player's final score. The player with the highest score wins. As these players all play with their best strategies, decide which one will win according to the sequence of integers.

Looks like an ACM-ICPC problem? Not really. It's really a game:)

**EDIT**

The players can't pass their turns.

Reason being, a player would like to pass a turn only if he/she has no incentive to play that turn. So if `player i` passes a turn, then any other `player j` would also see that they have no incentive to play that turn. So they would also end up passing the turn and the game gets stalled forever.

For example, the sequence is 1,2. 2 players are playing. The first one tagged 1, and the second tagged 1 too, so player2 got 1 point. Then player2 got another chance to tag, 1 can't be tagged, so he tagged 2. Now it's player1's turn, he can only tag 2, and he will get 2 points after he tags 2. After this game, player1 gets 2 points while player2 gets 1. So player1 wins.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here.  Are you looking for an algorithm to help you solve this?   Pointers? (Both are a bit too broad.)

Comment: Do you have any code to go along with this? it's hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is interesting. However, you fail to ask a specific question. I believe what you want to ask for is the theory behind it or how an algorithm would solve this, but that's not apparent from your post. Also, can you please link to the source of this problem?

Comment: Can a player pass their turn? It seems like it's possible to end up in a situation where someone cannot move, but the other can.

Comment: @MxyL The players have the same possible set of moves, so the kind of situation you're talking about can not occur. Note that all players operate on the same sequence of numbers

Comment: why was this put on hold. I don't think there can be too many possible answers. And an answer would not be too long.

Comment: @Niklas B. Thank you for asking my question. I'm sorry for didn't say quite clearly, and something has been added just now. For addition, I'm looking for an algorithm solving this problem, that means, with the array given, how many points can player1 get and how should he do?

Comment: since the numbers are `non-decreasing` and not `increasing` there can be a possibility for a tie.
For `m=2`, if `n` is `even`, `player1` will win. If `n` is `odd` `player2` will win.
At any turn, `player i` has two options. 1.take `all` tagged integers and tag another integer.
2. just tag another integer.

Comment: @arunmoezhi You means that it can be solved by dynamic programming? I'm a little confused by what you just said. Could you explain "For m=2, if n is even, player1 will win. If n is odd player2 will win."? I'd appreciate if you show examples on n=3,4 or more. Thanks. :)

Comment: I believe the optimal strategy is to take all integers and then to either tag the smallest untagged one or do nothing. And yes, that latter part can be solved using DP (or maybe it's even always better to not tag if one does not need to)

Comment: @K2082: Assume 2 players. The integers be `x,y` with `x<y`. The optimal strategy for any player is to tag from left to right (`greedy choice`). As tagging an integer means the player is willing to give up that integer. `Player 1` tags `x`. Now `player2` is left with two options. (a) to take `x` and tag `y`. (b) to just tag `y`. In the next turn `player 1` responds to (a) with picking `y` and responds to (b) with picking both `x` and `y`. Now if you calculate the incentives for each player at all the leaves of this game tree, `player1` will have maximum profit.

Comment: If we have 3 integer `x,y,z` with `x<y<z`, `player1` starts with tagging `x`. `Player2`'s best response would be to do (a). take `x` and  now the game looks like a 2 integer game with `y,z` with `player2` starting the game with an extra profit of `x`. In this sub-game `player2` will win and eventually win in the overall game. And as @NiklasB. said this is a `DP`.

Comment: I think this approach is correct. If something is wrong with my approach please let me know. I might have overlooked something

Comment: @arunmoezhiI think the two options would be (1) take all tagged integers and tag the smallest other integer (2) just take all tagged integers and do nothing more (only applicable if there are some integers pre-tagged). Maybe you got that the wrong way round in your initial comment?

Comment: By the way, is the problem available somewhere online? I like to solve it

Comment: @NiklasB.I assumed that at each round a player must definitely tag an integer.